# Tagging questions on precepts

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen a lot of posts getting tagged [five-precepts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/five-precepts) when they are asking specifically about one of the precepts. That's fine, but do we want to standardize on some format for which specific precept is being asked about?  It seems like it would be desirable for someone to, for example, look at all questions around the first precept.

There are three ways I can see to do this.

The first is to tag it based on the number of the precept, e.g., [first-precept](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-precept).

The second is to tag it based on the aspect of the first precept that is being asked about, e.g., [vegetarianism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism).

The third is to tag it based on what the precept actually covers, e.g., [killing](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/killing) or [precept-killing](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precept-killing).

These are not by any means mutually exclusive, but I figured we should start the conversation since we are getting a lot of questions early on that delve into specific aspects of a single precept.

Comment: Precepts 6 and up vary from tradition to tradition.

Answer (score 3):

*If* we need tags for the individual precepts, they should definitely be [first-precept](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-precept), [second-precept](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/second-precept), etc. This appears to be the most canonical and least ambiguous way of referring to them.

Optionally, we could also add synonyms, e.g. [precept-killing](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precept-killing) points to [first-precept](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-precept), but I don't think we should add them unless there is a demonstrated need for them - [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) and all that.